# How to create a scope similair to AssertionScope in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#

I would like to use a similair mechanism as FluentAssertion does when using new AssertionScope(). How can it be retrieved?

Example:

```
using (new KeyScope()) {   //... here FluentAssertions does x.Should().Be(?); }
```

And when the scope is disposing, actions are performed.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. You surely can create a class that implements `IDisposable`, can't you?

Comment: ^^ => https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3oje3 or https://dotnetfiddle.net/eg344f